# My Event Handler prints a different reducer value each time [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-context

I created a context which has a reducer that has few properties that I am keeping track of their state.
I have 2 buttons that each one sets an active tool property. I click both buttons once each time to set the the reducer property ActiveToolName.

I have an event handler that does something when one of the reducer properties is equal to a certain value.
I am printing the reducer property value every time the event handler is called. It prints it as the correct value, but then it prints previous value. What is the problem here ?? Why does the reducer value ActiveToolName keeps re rendering once with a new value and once with the previous one

Here is a chunk of the code, can someone point out my obvious mistake ?? I am new to react

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer, } from "react";
          
import MapViewContext from "./mapview-context.js";


const eventsContext = React.createContext({
  History: [],
  CurrentSelection: {},
  SetActiveTool: (name) => {},
  ActiveToolName: "",
});

export const MyContextProvider = (props) => {
  const mapViewCtx = useContext(MapViewContext);
  const reducerFn = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "SetCurrentSelection") {
      let newArray = {};
      newArray = { ...action.selectedFeaturesDictionary };
      return {
        historyArray: state.historyArray,
        CurrentFeatureSelection: { ...newArray },
        ActiveToolName: state.ActiveToolName
      };
    }
    if (action.type === "ACTIVE_APP") {
      let toolName = action.toolname;
      switch (toolName) {
        case undefined: {
          return {
            historyArray: state.historyArray,
            CurrentFeatureSelection: { ...state.CurrentFeatureSelection },
            ActiveToolName: "NULL"
          };
        }
        case "SELECTION": {
          console.log("Setting Tool To " + toolName);
          return {
            historyArray: state.historyArray,
            CurrentFeatureSelection: {...state.CurrentFeatureSelection},
            ActiveToolName: toolName
          };
        }
        case "PANNING": {
          console.log("Setting Tool To " + toolName);
          return {
            historyArray: state.historyArray,
            CurrentFeatureSelection: {...state.CurrentFeatureSelection },
            ActiveToolName: toolName
          };
        }
      }


      const [reducerTracker, dispachToolFn] = useReducer(reducerFn, {
        historyArray: [],
        CurrentFeatureSelection: {},
        ActiveToolName: "",
      });


      function ActiveToolHandler(toolName){
        dispachToolFn({ type: "ACTIVE_APP", toolname: toolName});
      }




      if (mapViewCtx.mapView !== undefined) {
        mapViewCtx.mapView.on("drag", function (event) {
          // In this event which handles mouse drag movement on a 
          //map, that is where the value keeps changing, even 
          // though I am setting it twice, but the console logs it
          // once with the value SELECTION, and Once with PANNING
         
          console.log(reducerTracker.ActiveToolName);
          if (reducerTracker.ActiveToolName != "PANNING") {
            event.stopPropagation();
           }
        });
      }

      return (
         <eventsContext.Provider
           value={{
               History: reducerTracker.historyArray,
               SetActiveTool: ActiveToolHandler
               CurrentSelection: reducerTracker.CurrentFeatureSelection
               ActiveToolName: reducerTracker.ActiveToolName,
              }}>{props.children}
          </eventsContext.Provider>
        );
};

export default eventsContext;
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't seeing a console log from the reducer function, and the other log from the `onDrag` callback handler? This appears to be an issue of closure over stale state in the handler since the `onDrag` handler only references the value `reducerTracker.ActiveToolName` had when instantiated. You may want to use a React ref to hold a cache of the `reducerTracker` state that the callback can reference.

Comment: Yes I am sure, because the reducer function prints out a different statement, the handler prints just the name.

Comment: Using Ref Worked, but why would I need to use the useRef hook and store the reducerTracker.ActiveToolName for it to actually work and not change??

Comment: That's exactly what I meant... that you ***are not*** seeing the same log statement outputting two different values, but that you ***are*** actually seeing two different log statements, an "inner" and "outer", so to say. It's how Javascript closures work. The React ref is a mutable "bucket" that can store any value and reference the current value of at any time, independent of the React component lifecycle.